# ¿Cómo obtener datos después de una coma?

Tags: c#, variables, numberformat

Tengo un array que me regresa lo siguiente en este orden.

```
[0] "DAC"
[1] "settings,52,52"
```

Necesito guardar los datos numéricos, es decir, solo los `52` en determinadas variables.

¿Qué puedo utilizar para que después de la coma tome todo hasta que encuentre la siguiente coma, y todo después de esa última?

Estas son las varibles donde se estarían guardando:

```
dac_red = arreglo[1].... (primer 52)
dac_blue = arreglo[1.... (segundo 52)
```

Comment: utiliza split en el item que nececites y separalo por 'coma'

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad que buscas es un [split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8), es lo que puede separar caracteres con determinadas restricciones que tu aplicas, en tu caso sería como:

```
String[] result;
result = dac_red.split(",");
```

y para acceder al valor solo indicas el indice donde esta en result:

```
String mivalor;
mivalor = result[1] //52
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando el método [Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) que separa un string en cada posición donde aparezca el caracter especificado y lo devuelve en forma de arreglo (string[])

En una línea:

```
dac_red = arreglo[1].Split(",")[1] // Primer 52
dac_blue = arreglo[1].Split(",")[2] // Segundo 52
```

Si vas a usar todos los valores, es más óptimo almacenarlo en una variable

```
string[] aux = arreglo[1].Split(",")
```